# Static link libstdc++ using clang

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, static-linking, libstdc++

When I use GCC, I can build program on my Ubuntu 15.04 using this:

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

And compiled binary can run on "stock" Ubuntu 14.04 without any external packages, only standard updates.

Is there possibility do build with this static linking to library with **clang**?

Most common answers:

- using test ubuntu rep (`ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`)
- update server
- recompile on target server
- don't use GCC

is not suitable for me.

Just can I do this with clang for run it on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Comment: Doesn't this work? `-static -lstdc++`

Comment: @Ashkan No, unfortunately.

Comment: @vladon Options `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` works fine with me with clang++ 3.6.

Comment: @Danh Simple program like hello world also compiles for me, but for big program there are warnings: `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libgcc'` and `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++'`

Comment: @vladon there are linking flags, not compilation, hence warnings.

Comment: @keltar Hmmm... How to run clang linker? I thought it's `clang++ -static-libgcc -static-stdc++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test`.

Comment: @vladon yes something like that. I meant if your program have multiple files, this flags should only be used once on linking phase, not on compilation for each file.

Comment: @keltar Oh, yes, it works! :-) Write your comment an answer for bounty :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

clang is compatible with gcc on this matter. Basically for hello-world program that uses iostream to ensure `libstdc++` requirement (actual lib versions may vary between distributions):

```
$ clang++ test.cpp
$ ldd ./a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffec65c0000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff937bb6000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff9378b6000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff93769e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9372fe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff937f3e000)
```

Here is a dependency for `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s`. But if you add `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
$ ldd ./a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe5d678000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb8e4516000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb8e4176000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb8e4816000)
```

That still leaves dependency on `libc`, but that is a different question.

`clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-static-libstdc++'` means clang ignored this flag, because flag is useless in current situation. First two examples that coming to mind is compiling C code (which obviously don't depend on libstdc++), or issuing compile-only command without linking (`-c` flag). Since `.o` file cannot hold information about static or dynamic linking, this flag have to be specified on linking phase (and, to avoid warning, *only* on linking phase).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using -static-libstdc++ or -static-libgcc, just use clang's **-static** flag. It will produce a non dynamic executable, with everything it needs linked in statically.

On my test program, it produces:

```
[root@interserver ogrerobot.com]# ldd ./CppUtilsSpikes  
not a dynamic executable
```